# How can I set timer in LIBGDX

Tags: android, timer, libgdx

I want to change my balloon's location (randomly) in every second. I wrote this code:

```
public void render() {

    int initialDelay = 1000; // start after 1 seconds
    int period = 1000;        // repeat every 1 seconds
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            rand_x = (r.nextInt(1840));
            rand_y = (r.nextInt(1000));
            balloon.x = rand_x;
            balloon.y = rand_y;
            System.out.println("deneme");
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, initialDelay, period);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(56, 143, 189, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(balloon, balloon_rec.x, balloon_rec.y);
    batch.end();

}
```

initialDelay is working. Balloon's location is changing after 1 second when I run program. But period is not working. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't fire threads inside the render method, it's not safe, can cause thread leaks, a lot of other problems and will be harder to maintain your code, to handle time use a variable adding delta time every time render is called, when this variable is superior a 1.0f means that one second has passed, your code would be something like this:

```
private float timeSeconds = 0f;
private float period = 1f;

public void render() {
    //Execute handleEvent each 1 second
    timeSeconds +=Gdx.graphics.getRawDeltaTime();
    if(timeSeconds > period){
        timeSeconds-=period;
        handleEvent();
    }
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(56, 143, 189, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(balloon, balloon_rec.x, balloon_rec.y);
    batch.end();

}

public void handleEvent() {
    rand_x = (r.nextInt(1840));
    rand_y = (r.nextInt(1000));
    balloon.x = rand_x;
    balloon.y = rand_y;
    System.out.println("deneme");
}
```